# WordCloud2 having error with output_notebook()

Tags: bokeh, word-cloud

I downloaded the default code from 
https://gke.mybinder.org/v2/gh/joranbeasley/bokeh-wordcloud-notebook/master?filepath=bokeh_wordcloud2.ipynb

i pip install word_cloud2 and ran it only to see this error

````
Compilation failed:

../../../Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/bokeh_wordcloud2/typescript/extension_bokeh_wordcloud2.ts:351:13 - error TS2741: Property '0' is missing in type '(typeof Number | null)[]' but required in type '[PropertyConstructor<number>, (number | (() => number) | undefined)?]'.

351             gridSize:[p.Number,  null],
                ~~~~~~~~

  ../../../Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/bokeh_wordcloud2/typescript/extension_bokeh_wordcloud2.ts:314:9
    314         gridSize:p.Property<number>
                ~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'gridSize' which is declared here on type 'Partial<DefineOf<Props>>'
../../../Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/bokeh_wordcloud2/typescript/extension_bokeh_wordcloud2.ts:352:13 - error TS2741: Property '0' is missing in type '(typeof String | null)[]' but required in type '[PropertyConstructor<string>, (string | (() => string) | undefined)?]'.

352             fontFamily:[p.String,  null],
                ~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../../Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/bokeh_wordcloud2/typescript/extension_bokeh_wordcloud2.ts:315:9
    315         fontFamily:p.Property<string>
                ~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'fontFamily' which is declared here on type 'Partial<DefineOf<Props>>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Custom extension code is still tied fairly tightly to the version of Bokeh the extension was made for. That binder example uses version 1.2 so you would need to use that version, with the code as it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation i have upvoted ur reply... Basically it has to do with the dependency i am guessing?